# Probability Question with functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Question: Suppose $X$ has density function $f (x)$ for $a \leq x \leq b$

I'm fairly certain that this is a uniform distribution, which means that $f(x)= \frac{1}{b−a}$ for $a \leq x \leq b$ and $F(x)=\frac{x−a}{b−a}$ for $a \leq x \leq b$

I have tried using $g(y) = f(s(y))s'(y)$ to solve this problem.

I know that $s(y)$ is supposed to be the inverse of $y$, which I solved to be $X=\frac{Y-d}{c}$, then when I differentiated that in respect to $Y$, I got $s'(y)=\frac{1}{c}$.

But this is where I got confused because I don't know how to use $f(x)=\frac{1}{b-a}$ while using $X=\frac{Y-d}{c}$.

I think that I either made a mistake somewhere or that I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: The density function of $X$ is unspecified, except that implicitly it is $0$ outside $[a,b]$. In particular $X$ need not have uniform distribution.

Comment: If the density function is unspecified, does that mean that g(y)=f((Y-d)/c)*(1/c), just by plugging in s(y) and s'(y), is as far as I can solve this problem?

Comment: Yes. Note it should be $y$ not $Y$ and you need to specify the range of $y$ for which this holds (elsewhere the density is $0$).